# Vodaphone 875 Uninstall SuperSu

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, system-apps, superuser

I own a Vodaphone 875 model phone, which I rooted previously using Cydia Impactor. Installed SuperSU, everything was fine and dandy, and when I needed to transfer it to another person who wasn't comfortable with a rooted device, I used the standard master reset button within the Settings page. However, on startup, I discovered that SuperSU was still installed, and, knowing that it was now a system application for whatever reason, I attempted to reroot with Cydia Impactor again. However, something changed, I have no clue what (probably a Google update or the like), and the exploit no longer works for my phone. A quick google search resulted with people having this problem, on different devices, with the solutions being a flashable zip, which I have no intention of doing.

Therefore, my questions are as follows:

How do I remove SuperSU from my device, permanently?
Is there a flashable zip for my device?

Any help would be extremely helpful, as I have been looking for a solution for over two months now.

Comment: SuperSU gives the option under its settings to fully unroot the device. It usually works well. Have you tried it?

Comment: The only problem being that, when the phone was reset, it clears the su instructions, making the removal of a system app impossible.